# C to C++ printf

Tags: c++, printf

How would I change this code, preserving formatting to C++ using cout?

```
  printf(" %5lu %3d %+1.2f ", nodes, depth, best_score / 100.0);
```

Comment: 9 questions, and you haven't accepted a single answer?   Why should we bother to help you?

Comment: Do you absolutely _need_ to change it?

Comment: Which part of the conversion are you having trouble with? Do you understand what each of the printf components means? I've voted to close this as "too localized" because nobody else would care about the answer to this specific question. Please rephrase it to make it more general, such as by asking about how to convert smaller parts of the printf string. For example, you could point out the `+` sign and then ask how to force a numeric sign using iostream-style formatting instead.

Comment: @RobKennedy, a good answer could transcend the question and be much less localized. A general guide to converting `printf` statements. Unfortunately judging by the existing answers this outcome seems unlikely.

Comment: @abelenky You should bother to help him so that other people with the same question can find a reasonable answer and not have to ask it again.

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, I've never liked the ostream formatting mechanism. I've tended to use [boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/format/) when I need to do something like this.

```
std::cout << boost::format(" %5lu %3d %+1.2f ") % nodes % depth % (best_score / 100.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void func(unsigned long nodes, int depth, float best_score) {
    //store old format
    streamsize pre = std::cout.precision(); 
    ios_base::fmtflags flags = std::cout.flags();

    std::cout << setw(5) << nodes << setw(3) << depth;
    std::cout << showpos << setw(4) << setprecision(2) << showpos (best_score/100.);

    //restore old format
    std::cout.precision(pre); 
    std::cout.flags(flags);
}
```

Comment: What about resetting the format settings to their defaults after output?

Comment: Why are you using `setprecision` for depth and not `setw`?

Comment: @Shahbaz: failure to understand printf flags correctly :(  I just noticed I'm ignoring the sign flag on best_score as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use cout.width(n) and cout.precision(n);

So, for example:

```
cout.width(5);
cout << nodes << " ";
cout.width(3);
cout << depth << " ";
cout.setiosflags(ios::fixed);
cout.precision(2);
cout.width(4);
cout << best_score/100.0 << " " << endl;
```

You can chain things together:

```
cout << width(5) << nodes << " " << width(3) << depth << " "
     << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << precision(2) << best_score/100.0 << " " 
     << endl;
```

Comment: In the chain, `width`->`setw`, and `precision`->`setprecision`.  The chainables begin with `set`, the members do not begin with `set`.